# Is my well pressure correct?

Tags: water-pressure, well

I have a private well system.  The water pressure doesn’t seem correct.  I’m seeing cut-in and out of 30 - 60.  Everything I read says there should be a 20psi difference.

Should I attempt to adjust my cut-in pressure to 40 and increase the tank air bladder to 38?  If so, how?

Comment: You should check for instructions for you pressure switch.  If I remember correctly some switches have two adjustment screws.  One increases/decreases the cut-in/cut-off pressure a set amount,usually by 20 pounds difference(20/40, 30/50)  If you also have the second screw, it will adjust the difference between the cut-in/cut-off pressure.  I think that the 20 pound difference is only a standard, not a must be.  At a 20 pound difference you do not notice the pressure change as much, as you would at a 30 pound difference.

Answer (score 1):

20 is normal but it's not any sort of iron-clad rule. If it works, no need to mess with it.

The differential can be adjusted by following the directions for your pressure switch. Be sure the **breaker** (or fuse) supplying that is off, since the contacts are exposed when you can reach the adjuster nuts.

If the run time of the pump at the lower differential is not at least 1 minute, get a second or larger pressure tank so that it will be.